# How to hide soft keyboard onStartTrackingTouch the seekbar

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard, seekbar

I have 2 edit text and a seekbar within an activity. I would like to prevent the soft keyboard from popping up when touching the seekbar even if an edit text has the focus. I also tried to force the seekbar focus but it did not work either.

I have tried to hide the soft keyboard on the three SeekBar methods (`onProgressChanged`, `onStopTrackingTouch` and `onStartTrackingTouch`), and also one by one but this does not work.

Is it possible and how to achieve that ?

Thx

---

```
private void hideSoftKeyboard(){
    // HIDE SOFTKEYBOARD
    InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Activity.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    imm.toggleSoftInput(InputMethodManager.HIDE_IMPLICIT_ONLY, 0);
}

/**
 * SEEKBAR Start tracking
 */
public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

    // HIDE SOFTKEYBOARD
    hideSoftKeyboard();

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oups sorry, I found the solution after many searches.. Here is it :

```
private void hideSoftKeyboard() {
    // HIDE SOFTKEYBOARD
    //InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Activity.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    // imm.toggleSoftInput(InputMethodManager.HIDE_IMPLICIT_ONLY, 0);

    InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(mSeekBar.getWindowToken(), 0);

}
```